# Array values is not passed properly in backtracking

Tags: ruby

I have written the following program to find the permutation of all the elements in an array. The values are created properly but the problem occurs when I try to assign the generated sequence into a new array. The old values will get cleared and the new values are copied as per the array size

```
def find_perm(nums, answer, set)
 if nums.empty?
  p set
  answer.push(set)
  p answer.object_id
  p answer
  return true
 end 

  for i in (0..nums.length - 1) do
    new_nums = nums.clone
    new_nums.delete_at(i)
    set.push(nums[i])
    find_perm(new_nums, answer, set)
    set.pop
  end
end    

def permute(nums)
  answer = []  
  set = []
  element = find_perm(nums, answer, set)
  return element
end

permute([1,2,3])
```

This are the observations that I have found out while debugging:

```
[1, 2, 3]
47167191669680
[[1, 2, 3]]
[1, 3, 2]
47167191669680
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
[2, 1, 3]
47167191669680
[[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
[2, 3, 1]
47167191669680
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
[3, 1, 2]
47167191669680
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
[3, 2, 1]
47167191669680
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Even though not a response to your question, this may be helpful: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation

Answer (score 1):

The problem was each time I was pushing the same set array into the answer array so each element in the answer array will have same reference (same object_id).

Solution: Is to clone the set array during the each push to the answer array so that each element have different reference.

The solution:

```
def fact(n)
  return 1 if n == 1
  n*fact(n-1)
end

def find_perm(nums, answer, set)
 if nums.empty?
  answer.push(set.clone)
 end 

  for i in (0..nums.length - 1) do
    new_nums = nums.clone
    new_nums.delete_at(i)
    set.push(nums[i])
    find_perm(new_nums, answer, set)
    set.pop
    return answer if fact(nums.count) == answer.count
  end
 end     

def permute(nums)
  answer = []  
  set = []
  element =  find_perm(nums, answer, set)
  return element
end

p permute([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the approach you are taking is similar to the following.

Suppose we wish to obtain the permutations of the elements of the array

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Begin with the array

```
[4]
```

This array has only a single perumutation:

```
perms3 = [[4]]
```

(`3` in `perms3` denotes the index of `4` in `arr`.) Now obtain the permuations of

```
[3, 4]
```

We see that is

```
perms2 = [[3, 4], [4, 3]]
```

We simply take each element of `perms3` (`[4]` is the only one) and create two permuations by inserting `3` before `4` and then `3` after `4`;

Now suppose the array were

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Then

```
perms1 = [[2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2]]
```

We create three 3-element arrays from [3, 4], one by inserting `2` before `3`, one by inserting 2 between `3` and `4` and one by inserting `2` after `4`. Simlarly, three 3-element arrays are generated from `[4, 3]` in a simlar way. This generates six arrays. (Indeed, `3! #=> 6`).

Lastly we generating the `4! #=> 24` permuations of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` by inserting `1` in four locations of each element of `perm1`, the first four derived from `perms1[0] #=> [2, 3, 4]`:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

We can do this in code as follows.

```
def my_permutations(arr)
  perms = [[arr.last]]
  (arr.size-2).downto(0) do |i|
    x = arr[i]
    perms = perms.flat_map do |perm|
      (0..(perm.size)).map { |i| perm.dup.insert(i, x) }
    end
  end
  perms
end
```

```
my_permutations(arr)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [1, 3, 2, 4],
  #    [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1], [1, 3, 4, 2], [3, 1, 4, 2],
  #    [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 1, 3],
  #    [2, 4, 3, 1], [1, 4, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1],
  #    [1, 4, 3, 2], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert). Note that we need to make a copy of the array `perm` before invoking `insert`.

We could of course have gone "forward" in `arr` (starting with `[[1]]`), rather than "backward", though the elements of the array of permutations would be ordered differently.